# Swift: How to keep a view in front of animation

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiview

[image]

Whenever I press the add button I want the drop down view to slide from underneath the black view, instead of showing on top and then sliding down.

I used to have the black view in storyboard and it stayed in front of the dropdown view creating the effect of sliding from underneath the  black view. Now I removed that view in storyboard and created a new one programatically and I got this problem.

I tried the common methods bringToFront/sendToBack, but this didn't help.

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        blackView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 500, height: 100))
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        
        self.view.addSubview(blackView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(blackView)
        blackView.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(dropDownView)
        
        dropDownView.isHidden = true 

        addButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "addBa"), for: .normal)
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.blackView.addSubview(addButton) 
}
```

```
    @objc func buttonAction() {
              
           if (dropDownView.isHidden == true ) {
               
               openDropDownView()
           }
           else { closeDropDownViewA() }
           
           }
```

```
     func openDropDownView() {
        self.dropDownView.isHidden = false
        
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            
          var fabricTopFrame = self.dropDownView.frame
          fabricTopFrame.origin.y -= fabricTopFrame.size.height
          
          var fabricBottomFrame = self.dropDownView.frame
          fabricBottomFrame.origin.y += fabricBottomFrame.size.height
          
          self.dropDownView.frame = fabricTopFrame
          self.dropDownView.frame = fabricBottomFrame
            
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.dimView.alpha = 0.75
            }
            
            
            
        }, completion: { finished in
          print("dropDownView opened!")
        })
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does `openDropDownView` look?

Comment: @GabrielPires I updated it! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I added

```
     let currentWindowB: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
     currentWindow?.addSubview(blackView)
```

to

```
@objc
func buttonAction() {
    if dropDownView.isHidden {
        openDropDownView()
    } else {
        closeDropDownViewA()
    }
}
```

Comment: just a warning, if you add that on window level, you might want consider the effect on other pages. Since window is the top-most level of your app, that `blackView` will appear in other pages as well. And in iPad your app can support multiple window, hence `currentWindow` within `UIApplication` you might need to consider that as well